# Realizar una class que tendrá nombre, edad, altura y 2 métodos que indiquen si es mayor edad y si es alto

Tags: python

Alguien sabría como realizar una "clase persona" que tendrá 'nombre', 'edad' y 'altura y dentro de esa dos métodos que indiquen por pantalla mayor edad +18 años y si es alto, o no, si supera 1.80 m.

No funciona asi:

```python
class persona:
    def __init__(self, nombre, edad, altura):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.edad = edad
        self.altura = altura
    
    def mayor_edad(self, edad):
        if edad >= 18:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    
    def altura(self, altura):
        if altura >= 1.80:
            return True
        else:
            return False

persona1 = persona()

print(persona)
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no funciona? ¿Cuál es el resultado que esperas?

Comment: Si quieres que muestre un mensaje, en lugar de devolver `True` o `False`, pon un `print` en tus funciones.

Comment: @Mateo Es un buen punto de vista, no lo había considerado, quizás ese sea el verdadero eje central de la pregunta y ya me mandé con el debugging 101 xD!!!!. Mientras tanto, veamos qué dice el OP.

Comment: @fredyfx al principio pensé que lo que quería era mostrar algo diferente con el `print` o sea que debería definir la función `__str__` pero hasta que no lo aclare no lo sabremos.

Comment: Buenos días, en realidad no funciona nada de lo realizado, ya que no realiza nada y aparece este error :Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Ivan\Ingenieria en Organización Industrial\Primer curso\23-24\Fundamentos Informáticos para la Ingeniería\Actividades\Visual Studio Code\Actividad 1\Ejercicio 10.py", line 19, in <module>
    persona1 = persona()
               ^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: persona.__init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'nombre', 'edad', and 'altura'

Comment: Lo que se pretende es crear una clase persona con nombre, edad y altura que se introduzcan como argumentos, también dos métodos más donde en la edad diga si es mayor de edad o no y si es alto o no si pasa de los 1.85 m de altura. Perdón creo que no me explique muy bien anteriormente

Comment: En ese caso, la respuesta ofrecida cumple exactamente lo que quieres, márcala como aceptada, recuerda leer el recorrido https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas cómo funciona la dinámica del sitio, así te evitas confusiones, aumentas las chances de formular mejores preguntas y de paso obtienes tu primera medalla.

Answer (score 1):

A tu pregunta, le faltó agregar el error, considera que es importante, en especial en SOes. Haré una excepción por efectos navideños y responderé la pregunta, vamos por partes:

Al ejecutar tu código tal cual está, se genera:

```
ERROR!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 19, in <module>
TypeError: persona.__init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'nombre', 'edad', and 'altura'
```

Leyendo el error, la última línea dice:

```
TypeError: persona.__init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'nombre', 'edad', and 'altura'
```

Como está en inglés, vamos haciendo uso de Google Translate para traducirlo al español:

```
TypeError: a persona.__init__() le faltan 3 argumentos posicionales requeridos: 'nombre', 'edad' y 'altura'
```

Ahora, las palabras claves son: `faltan 3 argumentos`

Por lo tanto, cuando desees crear un objeto `persona`, ten en mente utilizar los parámetros correspondientes que has definido:

```
persona1 = persona() #incorrecto.
persona1 = persona("Rambo", 25, 1.85) #correcto
```

Al momento de imprimir en pantalla, especifica la propiedad del objeto:

```
print(persona1.nombre)
```

El `self` es una convención que hace referencia al objeto en sí mismo, todo lo que viene después, es decir, los demás parámetros son propiedades que le asignarás al objeto (en este caso).

```
def mayor_edad(self): # aquí, le quité el parámetro edad porque no lo estás usando, lo que quieres es evaluar la edad del objeto que tienes.
    if self.edad >= 18:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def altura(self): # aquí la misma estrategia.
    if self.altura >= 1.80:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Aparentemente con este código, ya debería funcionar, sin embargo hay un problema de nombres, `def altura` y la propiedad `altura`, te explico:

```
print(persona1.nombre) # aquí llamas a la propiedad nombre.
print(persona1.mayor_edad()) # aquí llamas al método, ese def mayor_edad(self)
print(persona1.altura) # aquí llamas a la propiedad altura.
```

Préstale mucha atención a los paréntesis.

El resultado:

```
John
True
1.85
```

Si lo que quieres es que te diga si es alto o no, hay que hacer un ajuste, para evitar confusiones, reemplaza el método `def altura` por `def es_alto` y al momento de darle un `print`:

```
print(persona1.es_alto())
```

Esto te dará el `true` que quieres comprobar.

Por cierto, recuerda realizar el recorrido https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento de la dinámica del sitio y de paso obtengas tu primera medalla. Éxitos con las clases.